# What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

The class is Product, methods are getName, getPrice and reducePrice:
I have created the constructor and the methods but can't figure out why I have an error with my instance variable private string name, how to create the getName and getPrice body for my methods. I have not created my ProductTester yet to actually print out the results, could use all the advice I can get.

```
public class Product 
{
    private double price;
    private string name; // this has an error???

    /**
      Constructs a product with a given name and price.
      @param name the name
      @param price the price
   */
    public Product(String n, double p)
    {n = name;
     p = price;}

    /**
      Gets the product name.
      @return the name
   */
   public String getName() // what is the body??
   { }

   /**
      Gets the product price.
      @return the price
   */
   public double getPrice() // what is the body???
   { }

   /**
      Reduces the product price.
      @param amount the amount by which to reduce the price
   */
   public void reducePrice(double amount)
   {  price = price - amount;}
```

}

**Revised Class Product:**

```
public class Product 
{
    private double price;
    private String name;

    /**
      Constructs a product with a given name and price.
      @param name the name
      @param price the price
   */
    public Product(String n, double p)
    {n = name;
     p = price;}

    /**
      Gets the product name.
      @return the name
   */
   public String getName()
   { return name;}

   /**
      Gets the product price.
      @return the price
   */
   public double getPrice()
   { return price; }

   /**
      Reduces the product price.
      @param amount the amount by which to reduce the price
   */
   public void reducePrice(double amount)
   {  price = price - amount;}

   public double price()
   { return price;}
```

}

**Here is my ProductPrinter class. Makes two products, prints the name and price, reduces the prices by 5, then prints again: I have errors with the system.out.println(myProducts.reducePrice(5)) and system.out.println(myProducts2.reducePrice(5)).**

```
/** A class to test the Product class
 */
    public class ProductPrinter 
    {
        /** Tests the methods of the Product class.
         * @param args not used
         */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Product myProducts = new Product("TV", 499.00);
        Product myProducts2 = new Product("Bed", 899.00);
        System.out.println(myProducts.getName());
        System.out.println(myProducts2.getName());
        System.out.println(myProducts.getPrice());
        System.out.println(myProducts2.getPrice());
        System.out.println(myProducts.reducePrice(5));
        System.out.println(myProducts2.reducePrice(5));
        System.out.println(myProducts.price());
        System.out.println(myProducts2.price());

    }

}
```

Comment: capital 's' for String might be it..

Comment: Note: use `name = n;` instead of `n = name;`

Comment: You should really learn about the basics of the language before asking this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `string` instead of `String`

So just put this

```
private String name;
```

And you are not returning the desired values in your methods `getName()` and `getPrice()`.

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Product(String n, double p)
{n = name;
 p = price;}
```

they are exactly wrong way:

```
public Product(String n, double p)
{name = n;
 price = p;}
```

then it should be fine.

Errors:

```
private String name;
```

should fix the error

Method bodies: You only need to return the variable there:

```
public String getName() // what is the body??
{ 
    return name;
}

/**
  Gets the product price.
  @return the price
*/
public double getPrice() // what is the body???
{ 
    return price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First it is `String` not `string`:

```
private String name; // Note the capital 'S'
```

In the constructor(`public Product(){}`) you are doing it wrong! You probably want to set `name = n` and `price = p` so that it can be used later in the program:

```
public Product(String n, double p){
    name = n;
    price = p;
}
```

And for the `getName()` and `getPrice()` methods you just want to return the appropriate value:

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your reducePrice method with below method as you are not returning any value from this method, you can not call the void method from System.out.println().

```
public double reducePrice(double amount)
{  
       return price = price - amount;
}
```

Replace your constructor method with below one -

```
public Product(String n, double p)
{
  name = n; // n = name is not correct as you are assigning name value into your local variable n
  price = p; // p = price , same case with price variable also
}
```